# Prevent JLabels from Growing in MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

I am trying to create a form in MigLayout. I want for any text fields to be labeled with a small JLabel preceding it, with the text field growing as space is available. I am successfully able to do this in the following code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("", "fill", ""));
panel.add(new JLabel("Testing"));
panel.add(new JTextField(), "growx, pushx, wrap");
frame.setContentPane(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
frame.setVisible(true);
```

The result looks like this, which is as expected (the JLabel is the minimum necessary size, the JTextField takes up the rest of the area):

[image]

However, if I put a JEditorPane below this and have it span the length of the whole window, the JLabel becomes larger and grows if I enlarge the window. The code change looks like this:

```
...
panel.add(new JTextField(), "growx, pushx, wrap");
//New line of code here:
panel.add(new JEditorPane(), "growx, pushx, span");
frame.setContentPane(panel);
...
```

Which causes a result that I do not expect (the JLabel has grown):

[image]

I've tried to fix this by adding MigLayout parameters for the JLabel, like `"growx 0"` and `"shrink"`, but this doesn't seem to have any effect on the size of the label.

How can I prevent the JLabels from growing in a situation like this?

Comment: have you tried "w min" ?

Comment: I have, but I'd prefer an answer that wouldn't require me to hardcode a size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out! The problem is with the parameter on the JEditorPane:

```
panel.add(new JEditorPane(), "growx, pushx, span");
```

It turns out that when using `span`, `growx, pushx` is unnecessary (because it already grows in size) and when used in conjunction with this, it creates the effect shown above. My guess is that `growx` applies to all cells marked by `span`, but `pushx` only applies to the first cell.

So `span` makes the component take up multiple cells, they all were assigned the default `growx` weight, but `pushx` only makes the first cell grow.

So the proper way to fix the line is simply:

```
panel.add(new JEditorPane(), "span");
```